# Calling Override Methods

Tags: android

I'll use a simple example below to ask my question. I have a button that when clicked plays a song. Outside of my OnCreate() method, I have 3 methods, pauseMusic(), playMusic(), and onDestroy().

pauseMusic() and playMusic() are used within my Button's OnClickListener method based on whether or not the song is playing. My question is this, I had to physically type those methods out within OnClickListener, I know exactly when they're used, how come I don't have to type out my onDestroy() method anywhere? I'm noticing this a happens all the time with @Override methods. Are they just called automatically and at one point? Thank you.

```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.peterock);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playButton);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                pauseMusic();
            }else{
                playMusic();
            }
        }
    });

}

public void pauseMusic(){
    if (mediaPlayer!=null){
        mediaPlayer.pause();
        btn.setText("Play");
    }
}

public void playMusic(){
    if (mediaPlayer!=null){
        mediaPlayer.start();
        btn.setText("Pause");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (mediaPlayer!= null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
}
```

Comment: Could you be a little more clear?

Comment: The protected void onDestroy() method is used in my program to clear up memory space but I never actually type it out in my onCreate() method like I did the other two methods (playMusic(), pauseMusic() ). Why is that and when does it get called? Is it right after the onCreate() is done with its functions?

Comment: I'm kind of new to android studio and mostly programmed in C++, so I'm just curious how a method can executed when it's never called in your main function, onCreate() in this case.

Comment: yes. those methods are called by the system as part of the lifecycle of your activity. note that you didn't have to instanciate the activity either. The @Override just indicates that those methods are declared higher up in the class hierarchy, which means that they are known, even though you implement them.

Comment: @MarkF `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()` are `Activity` [lifecycle methods](http://www.codelearn.org/android-tutorial/android-activity). They are called automatically based on whether the [current Activity is in the foreground, in the background but running, or being destroyed](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle). If you feel brave and still curious, you can see the source code for the `Activity` class [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/app/Activity.java#Activity).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I'm understanding your question, but let mey try, This happens because of the Android Activity Lifecycle, there's a chain of responsability within your Activity, which the onCreate is the first to be called, and the onDestroy is the last, always been called after some triggered events.

[image: Android lifecycle]

When you override a method from a father class, your object becomes the first responder for this method. In the case of the onDestroy, the onStop will call YOUR implementation of onDestroy. In case you didn't have Overrided it, the method call you look for the super class implementation, and will keep climbing the inheritance hierarchy until finds someone who implements the onDestroy, it's a basic inheritance behavior from the OO paradigm.

Comment: image copied from http://web.archive.org/web/20140218132043/http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html